# Automatically adding a dynamic library to embedded frameworks via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, cocoapods

I'm creating a custom Objective-C framework (dynamic library) and attempting to pull it into a consumer application using Cocoapods. If I don't add the framework as an embedded binary, I get a nasty runtime error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXX/MyFramework.app/MyFramework
Reason: image not found
```

My understanding is that as a 3rd party custom framework, I *have* to add it as an embedded binary (due to Apple's concerns about dynamically linking random frameworks). Is that right?

If not, can I change my framework or Podspec file somehow so I don't need to embed it (without making it a static library)?

Otherwise, is there a way to automate adding the framework to embedded binaries on `pod install`?

Answer (score 2):

By default, cocoapods tries to link pods as static libraries. You can force cocoapods to use frameworks instead by adding [use_frameworks!](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#use_frameworks_bang) in your Podfile. Or you can probably try to set appropriately [`xcconfig`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#xcconfig) or/and [`vendored_framework`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks) in your library podspec file to link with your framework. I've seen a good example in [Sparkle project's podspec file](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/blob/master/Sparkle.podspec). Sparkle uses a `vendored_framework` workaround to get dynamic linking working in OSX (i believe because of [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3015) issue in cocoapods repo).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I replicated the settings in Sparkle project's podspec but I still can't get around the linking issue. For now we're just going to force our consumer app to embed the framework manually.

Comment: Sparkle does a little tricky - it references the compiled framework an the embedding works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact issue (Objective C framework built as Module with dynamic library) and finally found a solution:

After pod install, you must go to the main project's Build Phases in Embed Pods Frameworks and add MyFramework.framework to the Input Files section.
If your Framework is distributed with a bundle, you must add it to the Copy Pods Resources section in the same tab.

Unfortunately, this must be done by the person using your framework. If you have a solution that does not require anything on the user's side, please let me know.

[See Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsL8g.png)

**Update:**

It seems like if you do not specify a module_name and add you add your framework to vendored_frameworks inside the podspec, the steps I mentioned above are not needed, so no interaction is needed on user's side.

Comment: Did you need to give the absolute path to those frameworks? Or just the name of the framework?

Comment: In my podspec I have something like this:
s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFramework.framework'.
However, I also use the preserve_path property with the same input (not sure if this makes a difference).